# Can not connect to IBM content navigator web administration

Tags: websphere, ibm-content-navigator

When I tried to connect to the navigator web administration, I receive a message "The desktop can not be opened" and It require defining a desktop ID.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/npAjk.jpg

How to fix this problem or define a desktop ID?

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember if after an installation default desktop is admin or if you have to set it manually. Is your URL with ?desktop=admin at the end working (https://ecm.filenet.com:9443/navigator/?desktop=admin)? If it does, create a desktop and set it as default. If it doesn't, you should take a look at the WAS log (SystemOut.log) to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

After successful deployment of IBM Content Navigator, the admin desktop is automatically created. It is considered the default desktop until another is created with a valid repository. If you have issues, you should put in the full admin console address:

http://www.ICNADDRESS.com:9080/navigator/?desktop=admin

The desktop selection code at the end (?desktop=) can be used to specifically go to any desktop in the configuration, but the code treats the admin console address shown above as "special" for authentication and processes it slightly differently. I've had normal desktop configurations (especially after upgrades from 2.0.1 & 2.0.2) have issues for administrative users.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Content Navigator uses DB tables for it's configuration data. You can find the desktop related info in a table named `CONFIGMGMT` including admin desktop.

There are server possibilities for the error that you are getting

1. `CONFIGMGMT` table has corrupted data regarding admin desktop.
2. `CONFIGMGMT` table has been deleted.
3. The DB table is accessed by Content Navigator via data source created in your application server and the connection to the underlying database is not made due to authentication issues(very common due to password change policies).